como agregar fechas faltantes entre dos fechas en sql server?
Hola a todos quisiera saber si existe de alguna forma de poder rellenar fechas faltantes por medio de una consulta.
Tengo una consulta que agrupa por CIC(DNI) de clientes y por el mes del mas actual al mas viejo
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblsaldo2') is not null drop table #tblsaldo2 
SELECT
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CIC ORDER BY fecha desc) AS row_num,
   CIC,
   CONVERT(date,CONCAT(fecha, '01')) as fecha,
   saldo INTO #tblsaldo2  
FROM  #tblsaldo

lo que basicamente me da como salida esto:

como se ve en estas agrupaciones, las meses no son secuenciales, por que no existe el mes que corresponde, quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de rellenar los meses faltantes en las filas con los mismos datos de agrupacion y con el "saldo" valor 0 como en la siguiente captura

gracias, esta pagina me ha salvado de mucho..

Necesitas una consulta recursiva para crear las fechas para los cics.
WITH 
  fechas (rn, cic, fecha, min_fecha) AS
  (
    SELECT
      1,
      cic,
      CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(MAX(fecha), '01')) AS fecha,
      CONVERT(DATE, CONCAT(MIN(fecha), '01')) AS min_fecha
    FROM tblsaldo
    GROUP BY cic
    UNION ALL
    SELECT rn + 1, cic, DATEADD(MONTH, -1, fecha), min_fecha
    FROM fechas
    WHERE fecha > min_fecha
  )
SELECT f.rn, f.cic, f.fecha, COALESCE(t.saldo, 0) AS saldo
FROM fechas f
LEFT JOIN tblsaldo t ON t.cic = f.cic
                    AND t.fecha = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, f.fecha, 112), 6)
ORDER BY f.cic, f.fecha DESC;

Demostración: https://dbfiddle.uk/2CPf8WGP

hola, en la parte de la sub consulta, no me está reconociendo, no sé si deba algo que escribí mal ... tampoco entendí o de dónde sale

¿No te está reconociendo? ¿Qué quiere decir esto? No me basta mi español para entender lo que dices.

ok lo siento, en la pantalla me da el siguiente error, "invalid object name 'fechas'" ....y quería saber cómo funciona esta tabla.

Bueno, WITH fechas AS (...) construye una view o tabla que se llama fechas que puedes usar en la consulta. En este caso la cláusula WITH es recursiva. Puedes leer sobre la cláusula aquí: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

No entiendo porque recibes un error. Has cambiado el nombre de la tabla de tblsaldo a #tblsaldo?
